# How do I troubleshoot a 500 response from pypi when attempting to release a new package version?

Tags: python, pypi

I'm attempting to release a new version of a package to pypi.  This is using python 2.7, and I'm currently targeting pythons 2.6/2.7 for consumption.

The current release for the package in question is 0.0.2-1.  (The `-1` was a build tag convention I read somewhere; I'm changing this practice to use `b` for `beta`, which is more relevant.)

Basically, if I have the combination of `version` (in the `setup()` call) and build tag (from `setup.cfg`) that is anything other than the current version already on pypi, both the `register` and `upload` commands fail:

```
ethan@walrus:~/source/python-mandrel$ python setup.py register
running register
running egg_info
writing requirements to mandrel.egg-info/requires.txt
writing mandrel.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to mandrel.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to mandrel.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to mandrel.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'mandrel.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'mandrel.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
Registering mandrel to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (500): There's been a problem with your request
```

That's with a version of `0.0.3` and build tag of `b`.

But if I apply this patch:

```
--- a/setup.cfg
+++ b/setup.cfg
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 [egg_info]
-tag_build = b
+tag_build = -1

diff --git a/setup.py b/setup.py
index 14761cf..beb8278 100644
--- a/setup.py
+++ b/setup.py
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@ import os

 setup(
     name = "mandrel",
-    version = "0.0.3",
+    version = "0.0.2",
     author = "Ethan Rowe",
     author_email = "ethan@the-rowes.com",
     description = ("Provides bootstrapping for sane configuration management"),
```

Then the `register` call (and presumably `upload`) will succeed:

```
ethan@walrus:~/source/python-mandrel$ python setup.py register
running register
...
running check
Registering mandrel to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
```

If I change the build tag to `-2`, say, the `register` call will fail again.  This suggests the failure is related to any total version string that isn't already known to pypi.

Unfortunately, the `--show-response` option when using `upload` is unhelpful when the server responds with a 500 code; `distutils`' `upload` command merely reports the fact that the server experienced an error, with nothing useful to go on.

Any suggestions on what I might do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you tried Wireshark/tcpdump to get the full server response?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a 500 error also, the issue for that with the diagnosis from them is here: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3573564&group_id=66150&atid=513503 .

I debugged it using pdb.  The show-response option isn't really implemented in a useful way, apparently.  I put an "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" in my Python dist, in `distutils/command/register.py` on line 291, which in my release is inside the method `post_to_server()`.  I do a "print req.data" right there and then "next" through it in order to see the response installed inside the exception catch.

Comment: Thanks.  While it's unfortunate this was more widespread than me, I'm at least somewhat pleased to know I'm not doing anything blatantly stupid (in this particular case).